# Making a first Visual Basic function for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first time I research about Visual Basic programming language but, as it is the language used to make functions in excel, I need to know.

I have written the following function.

```
Function getNMinMax(cell As Integer) As Integer
    Dim res As Integer = 0
    For n As Integer = 8 To 1 Step -(n/2)
        res = res + n
    Next n
End Function
```

But according to Excel, it is syntactically incorrect since the second line of code. Besides, this kind of error also happens in some of the next lines.

Any idea about what are the syntax errors in my function? Is there any chance to make functions in excel files by using any other programming language like C or Java?

I would appreciate any possible solution.

Thank you and regards.

Comment: You cannot make half steps `Step -(n/2)` and the syntax must be `For n = 8 To 1` and `Dim res As Integer = 0` needs to be `Dim res As Integer` and `res = 0`. What do you expect your function to do? Can you describe it and give some input data and desired output data?

Comment: You cannot declare and initialise variable at the same time. `Dim res As integer` should be sufficient as it starts at 0. Variable used as Index for the `For` loop should be declared first as well `Dim n As Long: For n = 8 to 1 Step -1` to loop backward, I'm not sure what are you trying to do with `Step -(n/2)`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ `You cannot make half steps Step -(n/2)` - why not?

Comment: @GSerg Fist because of `Integer` and second if you change it to `Single` or `Double` it is just a question of time until you run into a floating point precision problem (see [Understanding Floating Point Precision, aka “Why does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers?”](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)). You can solve that precision issue using a `Do` loop.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Sure, that's shooting yourself in the foot, but you *can* - and with [`CCur`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions#ccur-function-example) or [`CDec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions#cdec-function-example), it's even reliable.

Comment: @GSerg Well, yes but I'm not going to recommend that to someone who is obviously new to VBA and since I know no way with a `For` loop to overcome the floating point precision problem that means you can't because it will for sure produce errors and not run as expected.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ `I know no way with a For loop to overcome the floating point precision problem` - `Step CCur(-0.5)`? `Step CDec(-0.5)`?

Comment: @GSerg Well, ok didn't know that (but still more obvious the argument with the `Integers`). Anyway, do you have any good source about why precision problems do not occur with a decimal vs a double? I'm interested.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Because they are fixed point data types invented specifically for that reason? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/decimal-data-type, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/currency-data-type

Comment: @GSerg Ah, I see technically they are integers ^^. Makes sense, Many thanks!